# import of a function fails

Tags: python-3.x, function, import, streamlit

I've written this code for the homepage of my streamlit app:

```
import streamlit as st  
from streamlit_login_auth_ui.widgets import __login__

__login__obj = __login__(auth_token = st.secrets['courier_auth_token'], 
                    company_name = "The Suite",
                    width = 200, height = 250, 
                    logout_button_name = 'Logout',
                    hide_menu_bool = False, 
                    hide_footer_bool = True, 
                    lottie_url = 'https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_jcikwtux.json'
                    )

LOGGED_IN = __login__obj.build_login_ui()

if LOGGED_IN != True:
    with open('style3.css') as f:
        st.markdown(f'<style>{f.read()}</style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

if LOGGED_IN == True:
    st.sidebar.success('Select a page above')

    username = __login__obj.get_username()

    if username =='Liscivia':
        def show_download_Json():
            with open('_secret_auth_.json') as f:
                st.download_button('Download Json', f)

        show_download_Json()
```

I'd need to call the get_username() function to retrieve my user as an admin to be able to download a file.
This is the repo that I used to create the login form:
https://github.com/GauriSP10/streamlit_login_auth_ui/
and this is an issue that has been resolved regarding the function:
https://github.com/GauriSP10/streamlit_login_auth_ui/issues/2
, this file also shows an example of the function in use:
https://github.com/GauriSP10/streamlit_login_auth_ui/blob/main/app.py

The import of the function fails though, what could be the problem given that the library is correctly installed and updated to the latest version (0.2.0)?

This is the error I get:

```
AttributeError: '__login__' object has no attribute 'get_username'
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\gianm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 562, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\gianm\Py_Projects\Indicator_Suite\Home.py", line 36, in <module>
    username = __login__obj.get_username()
```

Also trying updating python to 3.11 but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code where `get_username()` is implemented is not yet updated in pypi. You can install the latest code by downloading the whole repo with git clone command.

##### Step 1

From command line.

```
git clone https://github.com/GauriSP10/streamlit_login_auth_ui.git
```

##### Step 2

```
cd streamlit_login_auth_ui
```

##### Step 3

Install the latest code.

```
pip install .
```

The last character is dot.

Run your streamlit app again and it will return a username.

#### Sample code

```
LOGGED_IN = __login__obj.build_login_ui()

if LOGGED_IN:
    st.markdown("Your Streamlit Application Begins here!")
    username = __login__obj.get_username()
    st.write(username)
```

#### Output

**image 1**

[image]

**image 2**

[image]

#### Get username

```
if LOGGED_IN:
    if not st.session_state['LOGOUT_BUTTON_HIT']:
        fetched_cookies = __login__.cookies
        if '__streamlit_login_signup_ui_username__' in fetched_cookies.keys():
            username = fetched_cookies['__streamlit_login_signup_ui_username__']
            st.write(username)
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much Sir.
Secondly, wouldn't it become a problem if my app is uploaded to a streamlit cloud container?
Because I pushed it live with their service and if I can't specify a version of the login_auth plugin in the requirements file I doubt the app would run correctly.

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: If you use `get_username()` it will not function of course because pypi is not updated. Just ask the maintainer in github to update pypi.

Comment: I looked at the source code in the repo. Now I update my answer to include getting the user name. See `Get username` section. It worked from my test.